# Zend Search Lucene - Searching specific field

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

I currently have **Zend_Search_Lucene** set up as the search engine on the project I am working on.

It is working great at the default level (ie. searching all fields), however I have the need to now search a specific field.

The reason for this is because I am attempting to code in the capability of dealing with misspellings. I am therefore adding the soundex of each of the words in the document title.

**For example:**

```
$productArray['title'] = 'June Monthly Meat Box';  
$doc = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();  
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('product_title', $productArray['title']));  
$soundex = implode(' ',  array_map('soundex', array_map('trim', preg_split('/ /', $productArray['title'], NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY))));  
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::keyword('soundex', $soundex));  
$index->addDocument($doc);
```

This adds 'J500 M534 M300 B200' as the soundex field.

**This is how the search is performed:**

```
$queryString = trim(urldecode($this->_request->getParam('q')));  
$words = array_map('trim', preg_split('/ /', $queryString, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));    

$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean();  
$subquery1 = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();  
foreach($words as $word) 
{  
    $subquery1->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($word));  
}  

$subquery2 = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();  
foreach($words as $word)
{  
        $subquery2->addTerm(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term(strtolower(soundex($word)), 'soundex'));  
}  
$query->addSubquery($subquery1);  
$query->addSubquery($subquery2);
```

The variable `$subquery1` stores each of the words of the original query (This works on it's own)
The variable `$subquery2` stores the soundex of each word. The plan is to search the field for the soundex as well as the other fields for each word. Therefore if someone misspelt '**meat**' with '**maet**', it would return the result as the soundex would be the same at '**M300**'.

I am using [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to view the dataset and am seeing the correct terms. When I use Luke to search for the soundex (ie. `soundex:M300`) it returns no results, however if I search the entire field (ie. `soundex:"J500 M534 M300 B200"`) it returns the correct document.

What is going wrong to prevent it searching within the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::keyword correctly (what you used for "soundex" above), it is designed to store a single value at a time (like a single date or a single URL).

I think for the "soundex" field you want to instead use a tokenizing storage method like Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text, as it sounds like you want to search on individual tokens in the "soundex" field, not just the whole field value.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for the info. I originally had it as a text field but changed it. The reason for the change was because Luke displayed the top ranking terms for the soundex field as one letter (such as: b, s, r, etc). Therefore if I search soundex:m does bring up all the results where there is a soundex MXXX. What strikes me as strange is that there are no numbers in the terms. Are numbers ignored for tokenized fields?

Comment: Sorted it, I had to change the default analyzer as I've learnt it doesn't treat numbers as part of terms. I added `Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault( new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive() );` before the index was created and before the index was searched.